# How to use Shared Drive as multiple Kubernetes PV in Homelab

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, persistent-volumes

I have homelab.
`Window Host` and `Vmware workstation`

```
1 Master Node
3 Worker Nodes
```

All  nodes have the  windows drive mounted and available `/external`

I want to run multiple tools like jenkins, nexus, nessus, etc and want to use persistent volumes in external drive so that even if i create new EKS clusters then volumes stay there for ever and i can reuse them

So i want to know whats the best to use it

1. Can i create single `hostPath` PV and then each pod can claim exmaple 20GB from it
2. Or I have to create PV for each pod with `hostPath` and then claim it in POD

So is there 1:1 relationship with PV and PVC ? or one PV can have multiple claims in diff folders?

3. Also if recreate CLuster and create PV from same hostPath , will my data be there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `local` volume instead of `hostPath` to experiment with SC/PVC/PC. First, you create the StorageClass:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: shared
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

Then you provision the PersistentVolume available **on each node**, here's an example for one node:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: shared-pv-1
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: shared
  local:
    path: <path to the shared folder>
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - <your node name>
```

And the claim that allows you to mount the provisioned volume in a pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: shared-pv-1
spec:
  storageClassName: shared
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
```

Here's an example pod that mounts the volume and write to it:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox-1
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  volumes:
  - name: shared
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: shared-pv-1
  containers:
  - name: busybox-1
    image: busybox
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    volumeMounts:
    - name: shared
      mountPath: /data
    command: ["ash","-c","while :; do echo \"$(date)\tmessage from busybox-1.\"  >> /data/message.txt; sleep 1; done"]
```

For [local](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#local) volume, by default the data written will require manual cleanup and deletion. A positive side effect for you as you would like the content to persist. If you like go further to experiment CSI alike local volume, you can use this [Local Persistence Volume Static Provisioner](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/sig-storage-local-static-provisioner).

Comment: Thanks Goham , is it possible to solve this problem via PV and PVC so that i can learn more on them?

Comment: Sure, checkout the updated answer.

Comment: what is diff between create pv suing `hostPath` and `local` as both can point to same location ?

Comment: `hostPath` doesn't influence which node the pod will run on, it will assume the required path on the host is always there. `local` is the opposite. That's why for your case unless you are experimenting, you don't need PVC/PV to use `hostPath`.